# Due to changing the order of statements two postbacks are required instead of just one, before …

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

If we have the following code, then when user clicks an Edit button, page is posted back and put into Edit mode:

```
protected void gvwEmployees_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gvwEmployees.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

    gvwEmployees.DataSource = ds.Tables["Employees"];

    gvwEmployees.DataBind();
}
```

But with the following code, user has to click the Edit button twice before a row is put into edit mode ( thus page needs to be posted back twice before row gets into edit mode). Why does it matter whether gvwEmployees.EditIndex is assigned a value before or after we bind GridView to a data source?

```
protected void gvwEmployees_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gvwEmployees.DataSource = ds.Tables["Employees"];

    gvwEmployees.DataBind();

    gvwEmployees.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the `EditIndex` property with a value different than the one it already has requires that `DataBind()` is called after the modification.

As described in the [GridView.EditIndex documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.editindex.aspx), it could also happen if EditIndex is modified under other circumstances:

> If you set the EditIndex property
>   after a postback or in handlers for
>   events that are raised later than the
>   Load event, the GridView control might
>   not enter edit mode for the specified
>   row. If you read the value of this
>   property in other event handlers, the
>   index is not guaranteed to reflect the
>   row that is being edited.

Comment: I'm not entirelly sure how to ask this, but - Since calling DataBind retrieves all rows and not just the row with index equal to GridView.EditIndex, I would think GridView wouldn't have any problems to put any of the retrieved rows into edit mode, even if EditIndex is set after calling Databind?!

Comment: I would think that you can modify `EditIndex` until the PreRender event is triggered. No idea why this does not work.